# Number written forward plus backward =100?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, arithmetic, percentages, palindrome

Is there a Percent where when written forward plus backward equal 100?

Example:

```
XY + YX = 100
```

*(where those variables aren't multiplied together but stand in for the 10s-digit (X) + digit (Y) = 10s-digit (Y) + Digit (X)*

I came up with this question bc I saw some ground meat that had a *73% Meat + 27% Fat Ratio.* Of course 73+27 does equal 100 because neither 73 nor 27 are palindrome of each other.

So, is there any palindrome that when added together equal 100? I don't think there is a solution, but like I said I'm no math genius!

And if so, how would it be written out first as a problem, and the proved by solving it? I'd love to see your work in figuring this out. I'm by no means a Mathematician, so I have no idea how to write this out except in the example above.

This has nothing to do with school or anything, I just became curious when I saw the very similar numbers on my package of ground beef.

I think the actual equation would look like this, but I could be completely wrong:

```
(10X+Y) + (10Y+X) = 100
```

Is there any solution? How's it actually written and afterward how is it solved and proven?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

$$(10X+Y) + (10Y+X) = 100\\11X+11Y = 100\\11(X+Y) = 100$$
The left hand side is a multiple of 11, but the right hand side is not. There is therefore no solution.

By the way, a palindrome is a number/word/sentence that reads the same backwards as forwards, so that is not the right term for these reversed pairs of numbers.

Comment: Oh, I see. I mis read your reply at first. Thanks for getting back to me! I think I can follow your reasoning. And you're basically saying there is no such number that would fit this criteria. Right?

Comment: What is the proper term, if any for my "reversed numbers"?

Comment: @Ev- Right. No value of X and Y can be chosen that makes the equation true because If you add a 2-digit number to its reverse you get a multiple of 11, and a multiple of 11 is never equal to 100. I don't know if there is a standard term for such a pair of numbers, but I'd just say one is the reverse of the other.

Comment: 44.55 is a close approach once going to decimals.